# Calculate the distribution distance between two datasets

Tags: distributions, distance

I have got two databases $X_{S}$ and $X_{T}$ which are having different number of samples but the same size of feature-space. I am wandering which is the most efficient way to calculate the distance of those databases. How can I calculate the distance between their distributions?

Answer (score 1):

If you do know their distributions, you can use the KL-divergence to calculate the distance between their distributions. The problem is when you do not have any knowledge about their pdf s. You can perhaps have a look at [this](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/tatti07a/tatti07a.pdf) paper.
Good luck

Comment: A small suggestion: It is usually better to refer to papers by both a link and citation (at least title + authors) so that the paper can be recovered even if the link becomes dead.